# unwanted display: none added automatically on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, panel

I've a panel with a copy link inside, when I click to open my panel a display:none is added automatically

to solve that i added this line on my jquery part: `showme.style.display = "none";` now we can open the panel perfectly but it's impossible to close it after

someone have a solution ?

[here](http://500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/0/index2.html) is my link **WITHOUT**  `showme.style.display = "none";`:

[here](http://500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/0/index.html) is my link and here is my code **WITH**  `showme.style.display = "none";`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<style>

div#panel1 { 
    display: block; 
    background-color:#eee; 
    visibility: hidden;
}

.flip1  { 
    display: block; 
    background-color:#eee;
}

#check  { 
    visibility: hidden; 
    width:12px; height:12px;
}
span#copy-callbacks, span#copy-callbacks2 { 
    float: none; cursor:pointer; 
}
.zclip { 
    border:1px solid red; 
    position:relative; 
    display:inherit; 
}
div#zclip-ZeroClipboardMovie_1.zclip { 
    position: relative; 
    margin-top:-18px; 
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span#copy-callbacks").zclip({
        path:"ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy:$('#callback-paragraph').text(),
        beforeCopy:function(){
            $('#copy-callbacks').css('display','none');
        },
        afterCopy:function(){
            $('#copy-callbacks').css('display','block');
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("copy-callbacks").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("check").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span#copy-callbacks').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css({"color":"#e0ccb4"});
        }, 

        function () {
            $(this).css({"color":"#000"});
        }
    );

    $(".flip1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

function newwindow() {
    var showme = document.getElementById("panel1");
    showme.style.visibility = "visible";
    showme.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin-top:150px;" onclick="newwindow()" class="flip1">Click to slide the first panel down or up</div>
<div style="display: block; padding-bottom:80px;" id="panel1">

<span id="copy-callbacks"> Copy link&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="check.png" id="check" style="display: inline;"></span>
<span style="font-size:0px;" id="callback-paragraph">essaie sans alert</span>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cbpFWSlider.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first link is working fine..what is the issue?

Comment: in  the first link you have to click two times before to see the panel, am on safari

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need newwindow()
2. For #panel1 : in document-level style, remove visibility and display.
3. For #panel1 : in inline style, make display : none

I am talking about the first link.

Comment: I did like that, but the panel stay open ??? 
div#panel1 {  background-color:#eee;}
.flip1  { display: none; background-color:#eee}

Comment: 1. Have you removed newwindow() ?
2. .flip1 does not need to be changed. in inline style of #panel1, make display : none

Comment: i removed new window and visibility:hidden, and changed display block of #panel1 by display:none; it's ok but my panel is opened by default, there is any way to have it close at the beginning ?

Comment: if I remove the display:block; from my <div style="" id="panel1">... my panel is closed as I want but the copy link doesn't work !!!!

Comment: or there is a way to have display:block when we enter in the page and 1 second after an automatic display:none for the #panel1 ???

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/0u5zqfqw/

I commented some part of your code to simplify the example.

Comment: yep i understand the problem, but i think i'm blocked !!!! i need a display: block and none in the same time. The only think who can save me, is to have the possibility to have a display:block and none just after automatically. Did you think is possible ?

Comment: You can make a work-around for doing that. But zClip is not working on my machine at all..so I am unsure what is causing the problem.

Comment: I honestly don't know. zClip is not working on my machine at all, so I can't even test anything. One thing you can try is setting display : block in your style and using jquery set display to none in the $(document).ready declaration.